# Some question about localization

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a graded ring generated by finite elements of $S_1$ as $S_0$-algebra
and let $M$ be a graded $S$-module. For $m \in M$, if $m=0$ in $M_f$ for all generators $f \in S_1$, then $m=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a counterexample is $M=S/S_+=S_0$.

Comment: Then, Martin... for large enough $d$, if $m \in M_d$, it is true??